# PDF of $Y/X$ given a joint distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Suppose the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is given by
>   $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 2 & \text{if}\ 0\le y\le x \le 1 \\
>  0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$
>   What is the pdf of $Y/X$?

To start off, I know that I have to find the marginal pdf of $f_X$ which is 
$$f_X=\int_0^x 2dy=2x$$

I am not sure whether this is the correct way of obtaining the marginal.

Next it will be finding the cdf of $Y/X$. I have previously seen how to compute this if given a uniform distribution of $X$ and $Y$, but I don't really understand how to solve this problem, since $X$ and $Y$ are no longer uniform. I am also not sure whether my marginal derivation is correct. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Find the cdf $Y/X$, which is $F_{Y/X}(c) = P(Y/X \le c) = P(Y \le c X) = \dots$ then taking the derivative w.r.t. $c$ gives your pdf.

Comment: @user365239 Do i not need to find my marginal from the joint?

Comment: Are you trying to find the pdf of Y over X or Y given X?

Comment: @andreawong Try using begin{cases} and  end{cases} to create a piecewise function. You can click on edit to see the details.

Comment: @Arbuja Try to watch your edits, this one is terrible.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Why did you approve this edit?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Why did you approve this edit?

Comment: @andreawong Are you asking for the PDF of $Z=\frac{Y}X$ or for the conditional distribution of $Y$ conditionally on $X$?.

Comment: @Did from my understanding the question is asking about Z=Y/X, and I think in order to do that, do I not need to first calculate marginal of X and then find Z=Y/X?

Comment: No you do not, in fact I fail to see how the PDF of X could help. Instead you might want to check the section "Distributions of transforms of random variables" in your notes.

Comment: @andreawong Your comment does not parse, you will have to be much clearer if you expect some help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is given by

> $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 2 & \text{if}\ 0\le y\le x \le 1 \\
>  0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$

What is the pdf of $\frac{Y}{X}$?

Let $T := \frac{Y}{X}$. Notice that $T$ take values between $0$ and $1$. For $t \in (0, 1)$, CDF of $T$ at $t$ is
$F_T(t) = \Pr(T \leq t) = \Pr\left(\frac{Y}{X} \leq t\right) = \Pr\left(Y \leq tX\right) = \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^{tx} 2 dy dx = \int\limits_0^1  2tx  dx  = t $.
So, the density of $T$ is
$f_T(t) = \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(t)$ i.e. $T$ is Uniformly distributed over the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this makes sense now.